# Blazor app not loading files from wwwroot

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-server-side

I published a new app to an Azure App Service (Linux) from VS 2019.  The site loads but it's not loading anything from `wwwroot`, meaning the `site.css`, `styles.css`, `bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`, etc.  I see 404 errors for the files in the browser console but I checked the folders and all the files are there.  I also checked permissions on the files and folders all they way up to `/site` and its `rwx` all the way across.  I also tried to navigate by pasting the URL in the browser and I get a 404 there also.

Here are the errors in the console:

[image]

Compare that to the directory lists, and everything is where is should be. The one thing that throws me off is the double `wwwroot/wwwroot` but as I understand it that is normal.  I've tried removing one of the wwroot folders and it doesn't fix the problem.

[image]

**Update:**  I tried moving to a Windows app service but the got the exact same error.  So frustrating.  I need to go back over my app settings because it seems logical that the problem is stemming from my config and not Azure since both environments behaved the same.

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.  This is a new app and has been running perfectly on my local machine.  This is the first time I've had to configure a deployment so that's my excuse.  I noticed in `Program.cs` had an argument to set the `WebRootPath`.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    WebRootPath = "webroot"
});
```

I looked back at the article @akseki shared and changed it to the default args and now everything loads.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

I assume this was a default that was set when VS scaffolded the app.  I don't remember ever changing it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can cause this:

1. Make sure that your `_Layout.cshtml` page has:

```
<base href="~/" />
```

in the `<head>` section.

2. Make sure that your `Program.cs` has both:

```
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

You can read up on serving static files from `ASP.NET Core Blazor` [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: thanks for that.  I was only missing the UseStaticWebAssets().  Unfortunately it didn't fix the issues.  I'll give the article a deep dive.

Comment: You might also try publishing to a Windows App Service just in case. I remember reading somewhere that Linux App Services had some trouble with certain Blazor sites, but I don't recall whether it was Server-Side, WebAssembly, etc.